# Install stalls at Wifi set up

Tags: wireless, system-installation

Okay, did an Ubuntu install on an old laptop, letting the install program reformat the drive.  All went fine.

I just got a brand new laptop, and not being quite so brave, wanted to do a shared install.  I plugged the USB in, booted from it and at the second step was offered to chose a wifi connection.  I have two - an unprotected open, and a protected one (I live in the middle of no where, security is not an issue).  If I chose the open point and click "connect" nothing happens, the system just sits there. If I chose the protected one and input the password, it whirls for a minute, then asks for the password again.  I'm doing "show password" and I don't think I'm that bad a typist, but after doing it a 3rd time, I got to the next screen - with choices about loading other software.  The top choice (about loading updates) was grayed out because it said I had no internet connection.

So what's going on here?  Any guesses why it won't connect at all the preferred open point?  Or why it still thinks it has no connection on the other?  Yes, this new laptop was able to connect to the wifi when it was in Windows mode.

thanks, Larry

Comment: Just perform the install without connecting to Wi-Fi. The wireless chipset probably needs a proprietary driver. If after you install, you still have problems connecting to a Wi-Fi network, post a new question here containing the output of `lspci -knn`, and I'm sure Pilot6 or Chili555 will be glad to assist you!

Comment: Thanks.  The wording at that stop lead me to believe that if I didn't connect then that I'd never get the opportunity to get those parts ever again.  Not true I take it?

Comment: "I'd never get the opportunity to get those parts ever again. " Not true, indeed. I also recommend that you proceed with installation without a wireless internet connection. We will be happy to help afterwards.

Comment: Thank you!  Turns out I was doing it all wrong anyway.  I wanted to do a shared install, and let the USB go thru (and apparently chose wrong)  I got a working version of Ubuntu, but Windows wouldn't boot.  Followed many suggestions to get that working... ended up re-installing WIndows.  What  I should have done was done the "Try Ubuntu" install from the USB, then let that version install.  That ended up working fine.

I'm up and working on both WIndows and Ubuntu - yay!